# Spring redirect to new window

Tags: spring, redirect, spring-mvc, spring-security

I have a link on a page that requires user login to access. I've setup Spring Security so that the user is redirected to the login page (if not logged in), and after successful login is redirected to the required screen.

All well and good. But the user wants the new screen to show in a new window, so I can add target="_blank" on the link in the original jsp page, which will cause both the login and new screen to appear in the new window.

However, now the user wants the Login screen (if user not logged in) to show in the original window, and the new screen to show in a new window. This can, of course, be done with javascript, but is there any way for Spring to redirect the view to a new window?

Answer (score 0):

Whether a page response from a server opens in a new browser window, or if a redirect opens in a new window is ultimately determined by client side behavior.

Even if such functionality existed in Spring, it would ultimately be an abstraction of Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

No, it's impossible. The server-side doesn't know anything about the browser windows, and is  unable to control them. You may only handle this at client side.